# value of certain column based on multiple conditions in two data frames R

Tags: r, multiple-conditions

[image]
[image]
As shown above, there are df1 and df2

If you look at btime one df1 there are NAs
I want to fill up the btime NAs with **all unique + stnseq = 1**, so only the first NA of each Unique will be filled

the value i would like it to fill is in df2. The condition would be for **all unique + boardstation = 8501970** add the value in the departure column.

i have tried the aggregate function but i do not know how to make the condition for only boardstation 8501970.

Thanks anyone for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly then this might help.

```r
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  group_by(unique) %>%
  summarise(departure_sum = sum(departure[boardstation==8501970])) %>%
  right_join(df1, by="unique") %>%
  mutate(btime = ifelse(is.na(btime) & stnseq==1, departure_sum, btime)) %>%
  select(-departure_sum) %>%
  data.frame()
```

Since the **sample data** is in image format I cooked my own data as below:

```
df1
  unique stnseq btime
1      1      1    NA
2      1      2    NA
3      2      1    NA
4      2      2   200

df2
  unique boardstation departure
1      1      8501970         1
2      1      8501970         2
3      1          123         3
4      2      8501970         4
5      2          456         5
6      3          900         6
```

**Output is:**

```
  unique stnseq btime
1      1      1     3
2      1      2    NA
3      2      1     4
4      2      2   200
```